# Does this javascript function return a boolean if the array variable is null?

Tags: javascript

I working on a javascript code base and I keep seeing this coding style and it is confusing me.

```
var someArray = getSomeArray();
var itemInArray = someArray && someArray["someitem"];
return itemInArray;
```

I'm confused about the second line in the code. Is this what it is doing? Checking if someArray variable is not null and then returning an element inside the array? So what would it return if the someArray object was null?

Comment: [It would return `null`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical operators in JavaScript behave differently than in other programming languages.

MDN mentions that operator AND (`&&`) behaves in the following way:

For `expr1 && expr2`:

> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `false`; otherwise, returns
>   `expr2`. Thus, when used with `Boolean` values, `&&` returns `true` if both
>   operands are `true`; otherwise, returns `false`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

## Why using this?

The purpose of that code is to prevent accessing the `"someitem"` key of `someArray` if `someArray` is *falsy* (evaluates to false).

Now, this is a very implicit way of achieving this. A more explicit way of doing this is:

```
typeof(obj) === 'object' && obj['someItem']
```

Now, please don't refer to objects as arrays. A better identifier could have been `someObject` rather than `someArray`.

Answer (score 1):

This code pattern is useful if there's a chance that the array from `getSomeArray()` is null or undefined.

The first half checks to see if there is truthy value (which would be true of an object or an array), and then checks to see if the object has a truthy value for property `someItem`. This returns a true boolean value if its an array and has a value for the property and a false one otherwise.

If you try to access `myArray["someItem"]` and myArray is undefined, it will throw an exception.